# .htaccess redirect from url to url with param

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from an url to an url with parameters:
from http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/paramid 
to   http://www.domain.com/dir4/dir5?search=param1&task=search&id=paramid

I tried in .htaccess the following :

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/dir3/(.*)$ /dir4/dir5?search=param1&task=search&id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I can't get it to work.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess file located?

Comment: At first glance, your rule seems okay. You are using a permanent redirect, which might cache a bad try of your rule, but other than that I don't see a reason why it doesn't work. Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled, that you turned on the rewrite engine and that the FollowSymLinks option is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking for the `QSA` or `Query String Append` [Command Flag Block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

```
RewriteRule /dir1/dir2/dir3/(.+) /dir4/dir5?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Your solution is fine, as far as syntax goes, but there may be some lower-level functionality you're missing by bypassing the QSA command flag.