# Making a subdirectory redirect to another file

Tags: .htaccess, web, uri, redirect

I am working on an instant messaging application for android. I want to create a webpage which redirects the user to a profile inside the application.

So if the user opens "example.com/user/Name", it will redirect him to another page sending the "Name" as an argument. The application handles opening the profile and showing it.

I have got the application working but am unsure how to make the redirecting to work. The Name changes according to the user. What is the best to way to redirect without making multiple directories for each user?

Thanks in advance,

Aditya

Comment: I think your question was answered here already: [stackoverflow.com/questions/24309707/htaccess-redirect-from-url-to-url-with-param](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309707/htaccess-redirect-from-url-to-url-with-param)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite broad. You could try using a JavaScript to post the Name. The script could run on page load, so when the user goes to "example.com/user/Name" the script runs. Get the post function to send Name as a variable whilst redirecting the user?